# Generate sealed classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Using linq to sql I would like to generate some sealed classes in a data context. Apparently that can't be done.

When I try to extend a generated class, let's say `ApplicationUser` by a partial part like this

```
sealed public partial class ApplicationUser
{ }
```

I get compilation errors (summarized)

> 'SendPropertyChanging()' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'ApplicationUser'

and

> 'SendPropertyChanged(string)' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'ApplicationUser'

obviously because these methods are generated as `protected virtual`.

Is there a way to let linq to sql generate selected (not all) classes as sealed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a sealed class by editing the properties in the designer:

[image]

Comment: Gosh, can't believe I missed that! I've been poking around in those areas.